# Connecting two form webparts together - SP2010

Tags: web-part, connected-web-parts

I have a Parent\child relationship setup on a sub site. I created a page and added the parents list display form. I also added the child's list infopath form webpart to the page. The child list has a lookup field (named LinkID) pointing to the ID field in the parent.

I want to see the parent form (display form) with the data from its child in the infopath form. I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this task. Is it even possible? What would I need to do to get it working? Thank you.

Comment: You can't do this with SharePoint web parts or connections. You'd have to build an InfoPath form that queries both lists and adds the parent data, and a repeating section for child data.